# Why does the colour of gold sol change with particle size?

Tags: physical-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, color, colloids

Regarding the colour of gold sol, my book says

> Finest gold sol is red in colour; as the size of particles increases, it appears purple, then blue and finally golden.

This is the image I found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colloidal_gold) which portrays the same phenomenon.

[image]

The same page also discusses the effect of size etc. on the colour, but I don't understand exactly what's happening.

Why shouldn't the colour be the same for all sizes? Isn't it characteristic of the molecules which make the sol as the light absorbed and reflected depends on them?

Does this mean that when we break down any other thing to very small particles, it's sol will change in colour?

Comment: Generally, the electronic structure of a small particle is a function of size - the high fraction of atoms  that are on the surface alters the overall bonding. So, yes, changing size can change the color you see since the electronic transitions in the small volume are different.

Comment: Yes, the color of colloids is dependent on size. Besides absorption, there is scattering as well. @Natasha, read about the term plasmon, which is collective oscillation of charge density in an electrical conductor. This is the beauty of nanochemistry although Faraday the great knew about this property long time ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The color of conductive nanoparticles depends on [plasmonics](https://nanocomposix.com/pages/color-engineering#target). In brief, quantum behavior predominates in the few electrons of a nanoparticle, rather than as a continuous conduction band. [Surface plasmons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasmon#Surface_plasmons) strongly influence the color and polarization of light in sols and colloids. For example, for hundreds of years, stained glass has been made with [gold or selenium](http://1st-glass.1st-things.com/articles/glasscolouring.html) to get pinks and reds.

Comment: Does it mean that if we can create nanoparticles of something else, it'll behave in the same way? Or is it characteristic to gold?

Comment: @Natasha Not for, eg, a covalent crystal. Take sugar or carotene, in this case the predominant transition are those of the molecules. Those effects are evident in solid with extended bonding such as metals. Be careful to isolate various mechanisms. The final colour of the sample can rise from abs and various scattering mechanisms. The point is Au nanoparticles can be loosely    seen as "molecules". Look what happens at the gold levels when you combine an increasing number of gold atoms. One gets a reduction of the en. gap and a shift in absorption.

Comment: @Natasha Yes. There are many nanoparticle systems where the behaviour is dominated by the *size* of the particle. Semiconductor nanoparticles can be tuned to particular colours by size, for example.